# Unknown Error = -2,147,414,007 when trying to make a certificate to use GDB

Tags: macos, gdb, certificate

When I try to make a certificate to use GDB in Keychain Access on my Mac I get

> Unknown Error = -2,147,414,007

when I create the certificate.

Comment: You can see [Keychain Access error when creating new system certificate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302866/keychain-access-error-when-creating-new-system-certificate) for detail.